# Reading non-consistent textfile structure accurately

Tags: python-3.x, file-io, text-files

I'm currently trying to parse log and I'm running into an issue parsing entries that are longer than one line, a normal entry looks like this:

```
23/09/2020, 11:14 - Serial Num: Random Text
```

From here I parse the date:

```
dates = [x.strftime('%x %X') for x in datefinder.find_dates(t_str)]
```

And then I have this really janky regex that I use to capture the text **after** the the semi colon (when it appears because its not always consistent either):

```
pattern1 = "\- (.*?)\:"
y = re.search(pattern1, x).group(1)
```

My biggest issue is some entries in the logs go on for a bit before they move on to a new entry:

```
23/09/2020, 11:14 - Serial Num: Random Text etc.... for 6 new lines
```

I'm much more used to pandas and chucking it into `read_csv()` or doing simple line by line reading, so I'm a bit lost any help is appreciated!

EDIT: To clarify, each new line doesn't always begin with a date so I'm currently in the process of making a conditional parser but its a bit difficult.

Comment: If there is no number except the date in the starting of the newlines, then you can add an if statement, before parsing the dates, checking if the newline starts with a number i.e a date...

Comment: @Programmin-in-Python that was my initial solution however some entries are paragraphs so I'm currently trying to create what youre talking about where the new line read is based on a condition but its very difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: I've modified this solution a bit to where I wanted it, but it works for my specific use case, and shouldn't involve too much changing if it needs to be adopted by someone else. I've re-written it as a function for re-usability

```
def LogText_Transformer(in_path, out_text_path, out_csv_path):
    """
    :param in_path: File path in, as txt file
    :param out_text_path: intermediary Out path formatted txt file
    :param out_csv_path: Out path for written file as csv
    :return: Formatted log as csv
    """

    rx = "(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}, \d{2}:\d{2})(.*?)(?=\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}, \d{2}:\d{2}|$)"

    with open(in_path + '.txt', 'r') as f, open(out_text_path + '.txt', 'w') as fo:
        for line in f:
            if not line.isspace():
                fo.write(line)

    with open(out_text_path + '.txt', 'r') as file:
        data = file.read().rstrip()
        results = re.findall(rx, data, re.DOTALL)

    new_file = open(out_csv_path + '.csv', 'w+', newline='')
    with new_file:
        write = csv.writer(new_file)
        write.writerows(results)
```

The core code snippets are the first two `open()` calls, combined with `re.DOTALL` argument which solved this pretty well. Not the most elegant but it works!